# Time Picker not working

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap-3, angular-ui-bootstrap, timepicker

I have the following code and It doesn't show up the pop-up picker properly.

Here i my code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
   <!-- ...dropdown...-->
    <ul class="dropdown-menu customScroll dropDownLabel" role="menu" aria-labelledby="btn-append-to-body"
      ng-show="!vm.displayTIME" 
     >
      <li role="menuitem">
       <a href="#">Start Time
        <div class="input-group bootstrap-timepicker">
         <input type="text" id="timepicker1" class="form-control input-small" placeholder="" aria-describedby="sizing-addon2"
         ng-model="vm.startTime"
         
         />
         <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-time"></i></span>
        </div>
       </a>
      </li>
      <li role="menuitem">
       <a href="#">End Time
        <div class="input-group bootstrap-timepicker timepicker">
         <input type="text" id="timepicker2" class="form-control input-small" placeholder="" aria-describedby="sizing-addon2"
         ng-model="vm.endTime"/>
        
         <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-time"></i></span>
        </div>
       </a>
      </li>
  </ul>
  </body>

</html>
```

here is the screenshot of how does it look:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Do you include bootstrap.min.js and datetimepicker.js

Comment: yes. I have it included. I have the following in my bower.json:"bootstrap-timepicker": "~0.3.0"

Comment: Hope this demo will help you.http://www.bootply.com/OI0NGi7EWN